# Cannot find the process of an EXE file but can find the file itself. (Process.GetProcessByName)

Tags: c#

I have this

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("D:\\Program Files (x86)\\GameDog\\GameDog.exe").Length > 1)
            {
                console.WriteLine("True")
            }
```

And When I have this open and run it, it doesn't print true, even though when I try file.Exists it will print true. Am i using this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx, `processName` must be the name of the executable, not the path to it.

Comment: I also believe that it should be without extension.

Comment: Even with just the name of the executable it still wont enter the if statement

Comment: Okay yes, you need to remove the extension as well. Thank you